# How do I run terminal code on startup and running VPN on startup?

Tags: startup

I want to run this code on startup to fix my laptop from skipping brightness levels when I press the brightness up and down buttons:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo -n 0 > /sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled'
```

I also want to auto connect to my VPN on startup.

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Gnome and I have set up my VPN already in the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the command in `/etc/rc.local`. The `/etc/rc.local` file already exists, and it is a script that is always run on startup. You can just edit it and add the echo line. Note that command in this file are run as root, so you can simply add `echo -n 0 > /sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled` and skip the `sudo`:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^exit 0/# &/' /etc/rc.local
sudo tee -a /etc/rc.local <<EOF
echo -n 0 > /sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled
exit 0
EOF
```

If you know how to edit the file, you can edit it and add `echo -n 0 > /sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled` to the file before the `exit 0` line, instead of running the above commands.

Note that the script is run with the shebang line `#! /bin/sh -e`, so if any commands in it fail, the entire script fails. This may cause problems in booting.

Comment: so i would add the command and put it in /etc/rc.local and then on startup application i would select the file? and do i put it before or after "exit 0"?

Comment: The `/etc/rc.local` file already exists, and it is a script that is always run on startup. You can just edit it and add the echo line. I have modified the command above, since there's an `exit 0` in the file by default.

Comment: I dont know what EOF means. should i just copy+paster the script you put into the file after "exit 0"?

Comment: @Stackit If you know how to edit the file, you can edit it and add `echo -n 0 > /sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled` to the file *before* the `exit 0` line. If not, you can run the commands above in a terminal, and they will add the line. The command has been updated.

Comment: alright thanks! it worked. i have another problem idk if you can help me with. everytime i login i get asked for my gmails password to be added to the keyring but whenever i put it it tells me its wrong. I KNOW it's correct and i dont even know why its asking me for it because i can check my mail app and it auto logs in.
Oh and is their a script i can run to auto connect to my vpn on startup?

Comment: In "network" i added my vpn info from private internet access to connect to it.

Comment: @Stackit new questions! On Ask Ubuntu it's expected that unrelated issues be split into multiple questions.